# How can I achieve thread confinement more efficiently?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code, which is executed within threads. Code Explanation:

1.Each Thread `polls` a `Media` Object from the `LinkedBlockingDeque` and does something with it.
2.When the `LinkedBlockingDeque` is emptied, **a single thread** must `fetchMoreMedia`.
3.This goes on until another Thread sets the `DONE` variable to `true`.

```
static final private LinkedBlockingDeque<Media> lbDeque 
                                           = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Media>(LIMIT);
static final private int LIMIT = 100;    

public void run(){
    Media media = null;
    while (!DONE) {
        if ( (media = lbDeque.poll()) != null ) {
                // do stuff             
        } else {
            synchronized(lbDeque){
                if( lbDeque.size() == 0 ){
                    fetchMoreMedia(LIMIT);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// LIMIT is used as a param for readability reasons
private void fetchMoreMedia(int LIMIT){  
    // this method populates the LinkedBlockingDeque 'lbDeque'
    // inserting LIMIT values 


  for(int i=0; i < LIMIT; i++)
   {
       lbDeque.add(new MyObject());
   }    
}
```

My current code works correctly, since it makes sure that only one thread updates the `LinkedBlockingDeque` each time it is emptied, by checking its size in the `synchronized` block. But I feel that this is not efficient enough or the best way to do it.

Could you please point out better way/ways (that would not need to check for the `LinkedBlockingDeque`'s size) to ensure thread confinement in this case? or mistakes in my way of thinking?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what the `fetchMoreMedia` method does that requires synchronization? Also, if you aren't using the blocking methods, use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead, as you don't need `take()` and `put()`

Comment: I added the explanation of `fetchMoreMedia` (the implementation is irrelevant). The reason it requires synchronization is because **only one** thread should call it each time the `LinkedBlockingDeque` is empty